# How can the following ScanDataLabel output be reduced to the price?

Tags: c#, opos

A barcode reader provides me with the following string of numbers which is displayed in a text box `7612345203508`. In the string of numbers is the price at the following place `76123452(0350)8` Now I want to display it with a dot like in this example `761234520350    Fr. 03.50`

How can I represent this correctly?

My code looks like this:

VS2010 C#

```
textBox1.Text = axOPOSScanner1.ScanDataLabel; //Preis
textBox1.Text += "\t" + "Fr." +  axOPOSScanner1.ScanDataLabel.Remove( 0, 8 );
```

The output: `7612345203508   Fr.03508`

Thanks

Comment: parse the string, extracting the desired sub-string then format it

Comment: will that string length be fixed or does it change?

Comment: @Nkosi thx for answer, the string length is be fixed.

Comment: I tried that, but I have not succeeded yet. I'm still a freshman in C #

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for this example:

```
textBox1.Text += "\t" + "Fr. " + axOPOSScanner1.ScanDataLabel.Substring(8, 2) + "." + axOPOSScanner1.ScanDataLabel.Substring(10, 2);
```

But take into account that longer ScanDataLabel or shorter won't give you the correct numbers or throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Exactly where I was looking for, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

Try *formatting* and *string interpolaion*. If price consists of `4` digits at the end

```
string source = axOPOSScanner1.ScanDataLabel;

textBox1.Text = 
  $"{source}\tFr. {decimal.Parse(source.Substring(source.Length - 5, 4)) / 100:00.00}";
```

In case of *Visual Studio 2010* (where *string interpolaion* is not supported)

```
string source = axOPOSScanner1.ScanDataLabel;

textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0}\tFr. {1:00.00}",
  source,
  decimal.Parse(source.Substring(source.Length - 5, 4)) / 100);
```